# Apache, PHP5: Обработка <?, вместо <?php на Linux

Tags: ubuntu, apache

Настроил виртуальный сервер на Ubuntu 14, установил Apache+PHP5, если код начинается с

```
<?php
```

, то страничка работает. Если начинается с

```
<?
```

то не работает.

Решение: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php
This directive determines whether or not PHP will recognize code between ; tags as PHP source which should be processed as such. It is ; generally recommended that should be used and that this feature ; should be disabled, as enabling it may result in issues when generating XML ; documents, however this remains supported for backward compatibility reasons. ; Note that this directive does not control the http://php.net/short-open-tag **short_open_tag = ON**

Comment: В чём вопрос? php скрипты должны начинаться с `<?php`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: `short_open_tag` в php.ini включили?

Comment: Лучше скрипты поправить и не использовать short_open_tag. Уязвимости в нескольких CMS срабатывают только если эта опция включена.

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы интерпритатор воспринимал сокращенные теги:

```
<? и ?>
```

вместо

```
<?php и ?>
```

Необходимо в php.ini включить параметр:
**short_open_tag = ON**

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте [спецификацию](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_syntax.asp).

php скрипты должны начинаться с `<?php`. Почему вы решили, что просто с `<?` они должны работать?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: А вы `short_open_tag` в php.ini включили?

Comment: После ответа на ваш вопрос, нагулил манул, и вроде нашел решение. )